# Email Reminder on the day of creation & 3 days before the event starts

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, alert, sharepoint-calendar

I am trying to set a customize reminder for my sharepoint calendar. How can i configure an email reminder to be sent on 
1. Immediately after the event created.
2. 3 days before the event start.

Appreciate if you can help..

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new workflow for the specific list that look's something like below.

Create a variable of type Date/Time, then create the following logic:

1. Add time to date ( -3 days ) to CurrentItem: EventStart ( Output to Variable:varDateToRemind
2. Send first email
3. Pause until Variable:varDateToRemind
4. Send another email

**Edit**: CurrentItem:Created should be the column that holds the start date of the event.
[image]

Set the workflow to trigger when an item is created.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify that the reminder should be sent 3 days before the event. The date of creation can be anytime before the event eg.1 month, 2 weeks. So how can i make a workflow that can use any situation?

Comment: Ah, sorry! Let me make some changes!

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Timer Job instead, otherwise you are creating a long queue of workflows in progress and who knows **what kind of performance impact you will actually have on the server**. This depends on the number of workflows waiting at the same time and your hardware obviously.

Personally, I would not assume that all of these workflows would pause and resume successfully after long periods of time and you might do well to search for 'workflows not resuming after pause' online for several related stories!

Finally, waiting for a period of time and then doing something is just not the definition of a workflow. There is no actual workflow, is there? I believe you are looking into the wrong tool for your requirement, unless you cannot use the proper tool, which is a timer job.